# How to make items descriptions stack one over the other on a bill?

Tags: java

Making a program to bill clients. When a client buy only one item, i have no problem since i got this code :

```
System.out.println ( description );
```

What if a client buy more than 1 item.., lets say 3! This is what I want:

```
    System.out.println ( description );
    System.out.println ( description );
    System.out.println ( description );
```

This is the initial code for the description :

```
if (menu >= 1 && menu <= 4) {
                        System.out.println ("What is the item thay ou need ?(101, 102, 103, 104)");
                        numRepas = Clavier.lireInt();
                        if(numRepas == 101 ){
                            description = DESCRIPTION_101;
                        }else if(numRepas == 102){
                            description = DESCRIPTION_102;
                        }else if(numRepas == 103){
                            description = DESCRIPTION_103;
                        }else if (numRepas == 104){
                            description = DESCRIPTION_104;    }
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println ("***REPONSE INVALIDE!"); 
                }
```

Comment: You could add all the items bought to a `List`. If you only use a single variable it will be overwritten and only hold the last item bought.

Comment: How to use said "List" ? thank you !

Comment: Create an `ArrayList` and then use the `add()` method whenever the user buys something and add the representation of the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store the purchased items in a `List`, such as an `ArrayList`. These are special collections that Java provides to keep track of, well, lists of Objects.

For a simple use case like yours, where I assume `description` is a `String`, you would declare the `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<String> itemsPurchased = new ArrayList<>();
```

When creating the list, you should declare what **type** of elements it will contain within the `<>` brackets. In this case, that is `String`, but you could use any other data model object you choose.

The `ArrayList` has several methods, but one we'll look at is how to actually `add()` items to that list.  You do so by simply calling the `add()` method:

```
itemsPurchased.add("Item 1");
```

This item will be added to the `itemsPurchased` list. Now you can add more or even remove an item with the `remove()` method.

So how do you print out all the items added to the list? You use an iteration. You can either use the `Iterator` class, or a simple `ForEach` loop:

```
for (String item : itemsPurchased) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

---

There is actually a lot more to it and you'll want to review your design requirements. You can read more about Java from this [tutorial site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection` either `list` or `set` and then use Java 8 `stream` API to print the data i.e...
consider item description is in the string, So you will have a collection of the string and Java 8 will make it simple with an only single line of code as given below.

```
items.stream().foreach(System.out::println);
```